# Magento product list sort by product category

Tags: magento, sorting, filter

Im trying to add a sort by "Category" within the product listings sort order toolbar. This way when a user clicks a top category (lets say hardware) and sorts on Category, all the same products types are listed next to each other by category id.

Does anyone have a clue on how to make this work? Thanks in advance!